# How to do a db dump on AWS?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, dump

My website is host on amazon web services.
I would like to download a dump of my production db (mysql:5.7), in order to use it in my local project.
Do you have an idea of the way to export this db ?

Comment: You need to state clearly which DB (Postgres? Aurora? Oracle?) you are using, their dump/import commands are different.

Comment: @VictorWong The db i'm using is  mysql:5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download a dump of the file from somewhere that can access the production MYSQL server.

```
mysqldump -h <PRODUCTION_DB_URL> -u <USER> -p <DATABASE> > dump.sql

# Real example for your reference
mysqldump -h myremote.mysqlserver.com -u root -p production_db > dump.sql
```

Then you can import it to by running the reverse.

```
mysqldump -h <NEW_DB_URL> -u <USER> -p <DATABASE> < dump.sql
```

Finally connect to the DB.

```
mysql -h <NEW_DB_URL> -u <USER> -p
MySQL [<DATABASE>]> source dump.sql
```

Note that if the production DB and your new DB do not have the same user name, you will need to change the owner of the schema, database, tables etc.

Comment: Glad to help! Please upvote and mark this as the answer if it solved your issue.